# input type number does not add any constraint even set ng-step

Tags: angularjs

I am using input type number and want to allow user only integer value between 1-10  so added `ng-step="1"`  but it still allow float and giving no error

```
 <input type="number" 
        ng-step="1" 
        ng-min="1" 
        ng-max="10" 
        name="numKeys" 
        ng-model="vm.data.numKeys" 
        ng-required class="form-control" />
```

see [this demo](http://jsbin.com/cudozemifi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this just solve my problem

```
<input type="text" name="numKeys" ng-pattern="/^([1-9]|10)$/" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-pattern with the RegExp "/^[0-9]+$/" to accept only integer values.

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/">
```

Comment: this will allow more than 10. and that's not I am asking